# how can I import .apk file of the downloaded file into Eclipse? Do we have this option?

Tags: android

I am newb To Android.I just to check out few applications in my Desktop and have downloaded some sample applications. However, they are in the format .apk.
Please let me know the procedure to import this file into Eclipse which helps me to run the application.

Regards,
Serenity.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to test the downloaded *.apk try installing it in the emulator. Copy the APK file into **platform-tools** directory, navigate to *platform-tools* directory. Execute 
`adb install filename.apk` 
 
 If you want to view the source code of the *.apk. 
 Try this link [How to View the Source Code of an Android *.apk](http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-view-source-code-of-android-apk.html)

Comment: NOTE: The _**adb**_ file has been moved to the _**platform-tools**_ directory in the latest SDK download. So if you do not find this command in your _**tools**_ directory, check the _**platform-tools**_ directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna run the application you don't have to import it into Eclipse but instead you have to install it on your phone.

If you wanna see the source code of the apk file, you need a decompiler. There are some available in the Internet, however, all of them I have seen doesn't work 100% (e.g. they can extract the resources but not the *.java files, and so on)...

But you have to note that using decompilers could not be legal in some cases

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "import" them to Eclipse as they are binary files. But, you can test the applications using the Android Virtual Device:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html

In order to use it you will have to install the Android SDK and configure a Virtual Device:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Once you have installed and configured the virtual device, you just have to install you aplications using the `adb` tool:

`adb install applicacion.apk`

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are using WinRAR or other zipping programmes, right click on the .apk file with your mouse and open with winrar/winzip/e.t.c. then surf to the .xml files then edit them via notepad easily.

Answer (score 2):

If adb complains you have multiple devices, do

```
adb devices
```

Notice the serial number of the one you want, and then

```
adb -s SERIAL -r filename.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

File -> Import -> Android Code into Workspace -> (Select Root Directory (folder) of the Application you are importing) -> Check the (Copy projects into workspace [checkbox]) -> Click Finish [En Twitter puedes preguntar][DS]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the downloaded *.apk in the Emulator --> install it in the emulator.

How to install .apk file into Emulator?

**Ans:** Copy the *.apk file into SDK->platform-tools directory (where you'll find adb.exe file),

navigate to that directory through command line on your windows PC.

And then Execute:-

**adb install filename.apk**

If you want to view the source code of the *.apk.

Try this link [How to View the Source Code of an Android *.apk](http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-view-source-code-of-android-apk.html)

Answer (score 1):

Compress .apk with winrar, open it in winrar and click on apk file. It will show the content just click on extract. Now you have a complete directory structure of a source file. Try to repeat the import steps as suggested above.