# Downloaded foursquare apk but I can't edit in code

Tags: apk, foursquare

Downloaded foursquare apk but I can't edit in code because I don't have any libraries to import. How do I get the foursquare libraries into android project?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? What Foursquare APK are you talking about? An APK is a compiled Android application and you can't edit its source. For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658386/import-android-apk-archive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827248/how-can-i-import-apk-file-of-the-downloaded-file-into-eclipse-do-we-have-this

Comment: foursquare_2013-07-24_13-12_Paris_30979.apk
It was sent to me via an email sent by foursquare, but how do I excess the libraries for their venue database because that's all I want.

Comment: You don't need that APK to access the venue database. The Foursquare API is RESTful, which means you can just call our API directly through HTTP (likely through [userless access](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless)) or you can check out various helper libraries on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=foursquare+android&ref=cmdform